# .exe has stopped working

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm pretty new to programming, and this program runs, but when I am able to enter the batting record, the console is presented with a Windows error ".exe has stopped working...". This has never happened before, and as a new programmer, I think it's scary.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

//Prototype to keep console from closing.
class KeepRunning {
  public:
    ~KeepRunning() {
      system("pause");}};

//Define batting values
#define H  1
#define h  1
#define O  1
#define o  1
#define W  0
#define w  0
#define S  0
#define s  0
#define P  0
#define p  0

int main ()
{
  KeepRunning kr;

  int player;                 //Assign player number
  double sum;                 //Assign variable for sum of H, h and O, o
  double sumHits;             //Assign variable for sum of only H and h
  double average;             //Assign variable for average of H and O
  char size[100];             //Allows compiler to view user input as array
  int b;                      //Assign variable for integer size
  int letters = 0;            //Assing value of 0 to allow compiler to count

  cout << "\t\t\tBatting Average Calculator\t\t";

  cout << "\n\nEnter the player's number: ";
  cin >> player;

  cout << "Enter the player's batting record: ";
  cin >> size;

  bool invalid = false;
  while(!invalid)
  {
    invalid = true;
    if ((size[b] == 'H') || (size[b] == 'h')
        || (size[b] == 'O') || (size[b] == 'o')
        || (size[b] == 'W') || (size[b] == 'w')
        || (size[b] == 'S') || (size[b] == 's')
        || (size[b] == 'P') || (size[b] == 'p'))
    { 
      continue; 
    } 
    else {
     cout << "\nAcceptable batting record codes are: 'H','O','W','S','P'. 
            Please try again.\n"; 
     invalid = false;
    }
  }

  //Summate H, h, O, o
  sum = H + h + O + o;

  //Summate 
  sumHits = H + h;

  //Calculate batting average
  average = sumHits/sum;

  cout << "\nPlayer " << player << "'s batting record: " << size << endl;
  cout << "Player " << player << "'s batting average: " << average << endl;

  std::cout << "Press ENTER to continue...";
  std::cin.ignore( std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n' );         
  return 0;
}
```

Okay, so I've made a couple of changes thanks to yall. But, I've got new problems. First, when I run the program and write a valid input, i.e. "HOWHHHOOWHSPP", nothing happens. The console just stays open displaying the prompts and inputs. Second, when I write an invalid input, i.e. "HOWQQQTTSHH" or anything not including the specific set of letters, the console closes immediately rather than displaying my error message. How can I have the console not only stay open, but redirect the program to start over for any invalid input?

Here's the new code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

//Prototype to keep console from closing.
class KeepRunning {
  public:
    ~KeepRunning() {
      cin.get();}};

//Define batting values
#define H  1
#define h  1
#define O  1
#define o  1
#define W  0
#define w  0
#define S  0
#define s  0
#define P  0
#define p  0

int main ()
{
    KeepRunning kr;

    int player;                 //Assign player number
    double sum;                 //Assign variable for sum of H, h and O, o
    double sumHits;             //Assign variable for sum of only H and h
    double average;             //Assign variable for average of H and O
    char size[100];             //Allows compiler to view user input as array
    int b=0;                    //Assign variable for integer size
    int letters = 0;            //Assing value of 0 to allow compiler to count

    cout << "\t\t\tBatting Average Calculator\t\t";

    cout << "\n\nEnter the player's number: ";
    cin >> player;

    cout << "Enter the player's batting record: ";
    cin >> size;

    bool invalid = false;
    while (!invalid && size[b] != '\0')
    {
     if (size[b] != 'H' && size[b] != 'h' &&
         size[b] != 'O' && size[b] != 'o' &&
         size[b] != 'W' && size[b] != 'w' &&
         size[b] != 'S' && size[b] != 's' &&
         size[b] != 'P' && size[b] != 'p') 
       {
        invalid = true;
       }
      else {
       invalid = false;
       }
    }                   
    //Summate H, h, O, o
    sum = H + h + O + o;

    //Summate 
    sumHits = H + h;

    //Calculate batting average
    average = sumHits/sum;

    cout << "\nPlayer " << player << "'s batting record: " << size << endl;
    cout << "Player " << player << "'s batting average: " << average << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Learn to use the debugger. Set a breakpoint on the first line of your code and step through it. You'll quickly find out that you have an endless loop because your `continue` doesn't go to where you think it does.

Comment: The message isn't that scary, really. It just means your program crashed, which is generally not a big deal. As for the code itself, at a glance - `if ((size[b] == 'H')` your variable `b` is uninitialized here, which means its value is undefined.

Comment: Oh, okay. I set a breakpoint on the first line "keepRunning kr;", and debugged. There was a blue arrow pointing to int letters =0;? But, that doesn't have anything to do with continue....how can I have the program continue to "//Summate..." for the if statement, and return to the if statement if else is true??

Comment: Well crashing sounds scary, too! Ha. Okay, so I need to set b equal to something??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the problem is that you're attempting to use the variable b as the index to the array before assigning a value to it. I think what you want is a loop to check all of the characters entered by the user, so something like this:

```
int b = 0;

while (!invalid && size[b] != '\0') {
    //stuff in your existing loop
}
```

'\0' is automatically added to the end of the user input and indicates to the loop that all of the characters entered by the user have been read.

As a side note, it would be good to restructure your loop to check if the input you're checking is invalid and if it is, set invalid to true. There's no reason to use continue here. Something like this would be better:

```
if (size[b] != 'H' && size[b] != 'h' &&
    size[b] != 'O' && size[b] != 'o' &&
    ....etc.) {
    invalid = true;
}
```

The loop will end as soon as an invalid character is encountered.

Comment: Yes, that's what I want. Thanks for the example! I think I was confused because I thought that if I set b equal to 0, then it couldn't pick up the letter values I needed it to later. Also, that second loop makes everything more simple. I wish I could think like yall do on this site, but I'm thinking that will come with time and practice! Much appreciated!!

Comment: I implemented your new loop, and it worked well. The only problem now is that loop never ends?? It's just printing on repeat? Also, if I test against the loop, i.e. type in a jumble of characters which aren't H,O,W,S or P, the console just closes rather than printing the error message.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add that you need to put ++b; at the end of the loop (after the if/else statements). That just increments b so that you'll check the next item in the array. Also, to print the error message when an invalid character is encountered, just add your cout statement right under the invalid = true; statement.

Comment: Oh, okay. Thanks. I added the b++;, and it did make the iteration stop. But the console still closes as soon as I input my data. I can see it's doing something, but it closes before I can read it. When I removed the line ""\nAcceptable batting record codes are...", it stopped repeating itself endlessly, but it didn't continue the program either. So I'm thinking the program isn't running to completion either way. Any ideas?

Comment: Not quite sure. Might be a stretch, but maybe you have a line break in your quote that's messing things up? So make sure the string here: "\nAcceptable batting record codes are: 'H','O','W','S','P'. 
            Please try again.\n" is all on one line

Answer (score 1):

In the lines

```
cout << "Enter the player's batting record: ";
cin >> size;
```

I think you should take input to `b`, not `size`. In your code `b` is uninitialized, so it contains garbage value. When you use `b`  as index for `size`, the index is invalid, which causes your program to crash.

Comment: That makes so much sense.... I just wish I could think of these things!!! Thanks!!

Comment: Hi @whatsHerFace, if this or any answer has solved your question please consider 
[accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. 
This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some
reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: Hi @Rakibul Hasan, how to I post my new code to ask another question? Or should I just start a new thread even though it's for the same code?

Comment: Okay, thanks. I edited a post on this forum once, and somebody got mad and "yelled" through a comment that I shouldn't do that haha. But, I will! Thanks again :)

Comment: @whatsHerFace: If you edit your question and it invalidates the current answers or makes them irrelevant you should probably post a different question.

Comment: Okay, I can see that. Thanks @Blasfurnace